# NSXML Parser Skips the remaining string after &amp; In string

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nsxmlparser

I am working to download and parse data from a server.

avery thing is fine , but i found it is not taking some strings completely as they are,

after six hour of search :( I'm unable to find the issue.

i have to parse the string which contains **&** sign. and at back end (server) i just change it to **&amp ;** ,so that NSXML Parser can parse it without any issue.

**Example String**

```
Hello this is &amp; my test string.
```

what is all happening is,

i am just getting

```
Hello this is
```

rest string is skipping.

here is my code

```
message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    "<XMLBody>"
    "<Head>"
    "<Document>"
    "<DocType>Query</DocType>"
    "<DocDate>%@</DocDate>"
    "</Document>"
    "<UserName>####</UserName>"
    "<Password>####</Password>"
    "<Database>%@</Database>"
    "</Head>"
    "<Body>"
    "<Query>%@</Query>"
    "</Body>"
    "</XMLBody>",currentDate,myDBName,myQuery];
uRL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserverpath"];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uRL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
errorMsg = nil;
if (true)   
{
NSLog(@"Connection Build and waitng for response");
    xmldata = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
errorParsing=NO;
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmldata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    xmldata = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog("Result is %@",data); // here every thing is just perfect.
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmldata];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser parse];
}
```

in above NSLog everything is just perfect.

and when i reach here

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
[elementValue appendString:string];
    NSLog("String is = %@",string); // here i got half string

[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
// convert again into & sign

// doing my other stuff.
}
```

in this nslog just getting half of string.

what should i do get complete string as

```
Hello this is &amp; my test string.
```

Comment: Try to replace &amp; with & before parsing, after  xmldata = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; this line

Comment: replaced as you suggested , but output is again half string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will surely resolve your problem :)

I am posting it from my App. On server side i just replace all the invalid / special characters with these :-

From this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

just figured out `&amp; → & (ampersand, U+0026)` so i use a trick of using number 26 with % mark enclosing in parantheses to encode these sensitive values.

```
& = [%26], > = [%3E], < = [%3C], ' = [%27], \ = [%22]
```

get data with your URLRequest and replace these characters again in this delegate method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{ 
    [elementValue appendString:string];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[%26]" withString:@"&"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[%3E]" withString:@">"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[%3C]" withString:@"<"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[%27]" withString:@"'"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[%22]" withString:@"\""];
}
```

Comment: let me give a try to it